# Trying to pass in an environment variable in Module

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am trying to pass in an environment variable in my values.yml.j2 file which contains a bunch of ENV variables. Unfortunately, it is not working. Any idea Why I am not able to pass in any environment variable in my `app.module.ts` file?

```
@Module({
  imports: [
MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    server_name: configService.get('process.env.SERVER_NAME'),
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService],
}),
    VersionModule.register({server: process.env.SERVER_NAME}), //this is not working
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [ApiConfigService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

inside my `values.yml.j2` file I have this defined as:

```
  variables:
    - name: SERVER_NAME
      value: dev.ff.api.isp.kube.t-mobile.com
```

Comment: Can you show how you read the environment variables? How do they get assigned to `process.env`?

Comment: I updated the code a bit more to show my attempt at using useFactory, but this wasn't working here. I just am not sure how to read from environment variables. I assign the env variables with default names.

Comment: You still didn't answer my question. How/when are you setting the `process.env` variables?